# Universal Links Keep Redirecting to App Store

Tags: ios, server, app-store, app-store-connect, ios-universal-links

We are trying to integrate Universal Links feature in our app.
We have an associated domain and put AASA file to server. However, when we install the app on iOS device and navigate to the url we are being redirected to the app store instead of opening our iOS app.

So the question is: Should the app be published in the AppStore to utilize Universal Links or is there some issue on our side?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to test universal links with an unpublished app. Since you're ending in the App Store, my guess is that it's an App ID mismatch.

An AASA ties paths on a domain to a particular App ID. The App ID has this format:

```
{TEAM_IDENTIFIER}.{BUNDLE_ID}
```

Is it possible you changed the Team in Xcode to something else? You'd still see the same Bundle ID but the resulting App ID would be different.